# Optical matrix element in graphene: is electron $k$ perpendicular to $E$?

Tags: dipole, absorption, graphene

I faced some problems with understanding the process of light absorption in 2D (e.g. graphene). Suppose we have Dirac graphene hamiltonian, skipping all numerical factors:
$$ H = \hbar v\begin{pmatrix} 0 & k_x-ik_y \\ k_x+ik_y & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
All '$\hbar v$' and similar things will be omitted further. Diagonalizing this matrix leads to such a form for conduction and valence band states:
$$ | v \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \mathrm{e}^{i \theta_k} \end{pmatrix}, \quad  | c \rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ \mathrm{e}^{i \theta_k} \end{pmatrix}$$
Here $\theta_k$ is angle of rotation of vector $k$ in our coordinate system. Optical absorption is proportional to matrix element of velocity operator, which will be constructed of Pauli matrices:
$$ v_x = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \quad v_y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -i \\ i & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$
Matrix element $\langle c | v_x | v \rangle $ is proportional to $\mathrm{sin} \: \theta_k$, and for $\langle c | v_y | v \rangle $ it is proportional to $\mathrm{cos} \: \theta_k$. So the vector constructed of such matrix elements is proportional to a vector, which is rotated $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from $k$ vector:
$$ \overline{p_{cv}} \propto \overline{e_{\theta_k + \frac{\pi}{2}}} $$
If light which initiates these transitions is polarized ($E$, $A$ vectors are aligned on) the direction $\overline{\alpha}$, then the optical absorption of light with this polarization will be proportional to (Evans, 'Optical properties of layered compounds'):
$$ \mathrm{absorption} \propto \overline{p_{cv}} \cdot \overline{\alpha} \propto \overline{e_{\theta_k + \frac{\pi}{2}}} \cdot \overline{\alpha} $$
So the absorption is maximized when these vectors are in parallel and hence when $k \perp E$. It may seem ok as from Maxwell's equations $k \cdot E = 0$ in a medium without charge. However, in our case $k$ vector is not the vector of EM wave, but the vector of electron motion in a plane ($q$ vector of incident light was definitely perpendicular to a plane and $q \cdot E = 0$ automatically). I tried to explain it using the example of dipole antenna. If the current $j$ flows along the axis of an antenna, than the direction perpendicular to this axis is preferrable for radiation. So momentum of the photon which goes away from antenna is perpendicular to $j$ (and, correspondingly, $k$). From these considerations $q \perp k$ should hold. Then $k \cdot E = 0$ and $q \cdot E = 0$ can not hold simultaneously. But first of these conditions we obtained by direct calculation of matrix element and second we obtained from Maxwell's equations. How to resolve this problem?